# Defining a 1 to many relationship in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-4.0

I'm trying to create a 1:m relationship using Entity Framework (.net 4.0) and am getting the following error:

```
App_Code.Model.msl(36,6) : error 3007: Problem in mapping fragments
starting at lines 6, 36:Column(s) [ProductId] are being mapped in
both fragments to different conceptual side properties.
```

What i have is a Products table, and a Features table. The idea is that Products have many Features. Products each have a ProductId, and the Features have a ProductId foreign key.

Now the catch is that the foreign key doesn't exist in sql server, and i don't want it to. If it did, then it all automagically works nicely.

In the EDMX designer, i created an association from the product to the feature entity, then edited the mapping details of the ProductFeature association to be based on the Features table, which i think would make it work.

Any ideas? Thanks very much.

Comment: why dont you want the FK? forget about EF for a second, how would this work from a SQL Server perspective? You need the FK on Features to know "which unique" Product record it belongs to. If you're saying you don't want this FK, it sounds like a many-to-many, in which case you'll need a junction table (ie ProductFeatures - like the answer below states).

Comment: Is there any particular reason you aren't using a foreign key?  I understand it's a simple example, but it would seem from your description that it should be an FK.

Comment: @RPM1984 - I don't want to make changes to the database, because this is for an existing app/db, rather than a greenfields situation.

Comment: that's fair enough, but then that's a database issue. I dont think this relationship is going to work without an FK

Answer (score 0):

This is a M x N relationship. Why? Because a feature can be assigned to more than one type of product.

You should have a table ProductFeatures like so:

```
ProductId  FeatureId
1          1
1          2
2          1
2          2
```

Comment: Hi, this is just a simple example for learning purposes, in a real app you're right it'd be like you describe, however in this case i'm trying to get a handle on 1:m relationships.

Answer (score 0):

Found one solution: delete the scalar property 'ProductId' from the feature entity:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/a71901fb-97ec-4072-949a-c0c66a9775b1

However, in the auto-generated relationships that EF gives you if you set up the foreign key in the database, the eg 'ParentId' fields *are* present in the child as a scalar field.

So i'm a little confused still.

-edit- Further help:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CreatingAnODataAPIForStackOverflowIncludingXMLAndJSONIn30Minutes.aspx

Comment: Probably has to do with the code/xml generated by the designer.  I haven't used EF since version 1.0 but I remember there were many things you could do by editing the xml directly that the UI/Designer didn't support.

Comment: Thanks confusedgeek, maybe i'll just chalk this one up to the limitations in VS.